# Como descer um pouco mais os ícones?

Tags: css

Gostaria descer um pouco mais os ícones do WhatsApp, Facebook e Skype mas não estou conseguindo.
Segue o código:

```js
function relogio() {
  var data = new Date();
  var horas = data.getHours();
  var minutos = data.getMinutes();
  var segundos = data.getSeconds();

  if (horas < 10) horas = "0" + horas;

  if (minutos < 10) minutos = "0" + minutos;

  if (segundos < 10) segundos = "0" + segundos;
  document.getElementById("relogio").innerHTML = horas + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos;
}
window.setInterval(relogio, 1000);
```

```css
#menu ul {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #2f4f4f;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 306px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fffafa;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu li:hover {
  background: #ff4500;
  width: 266px;
}

#menu li {
  -webkit-transition: all .9s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .9s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .9s ease;
  transition: all .9s ease;
}

h1 {
  font-family: helvetica;
  color: #8fbc8f;
}

.center {
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-left: 35%;
}

.logo {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

body {
  background-image: Imagens/background-index01.jpg;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: center;
  padding: 50px 60px;
}

#relogio {
  color: #f90;
  font: bold 48px Arial;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 650px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yantramanav:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

<body background='Imagens/background-index01.jpg' onload="relogio();">
  <audio src="Músicas/Laura Branigan - Self Control.mp3" autoplay loop></audio>

  <div id="relogio"></div>

  <a href="page01.html">
    <div style=""><video class="center" width="500" height="300" autoplay loop>
                            <source src="Videos/Produce.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                      </video></div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.skype.com/pt">
    <div style=""><img class="logo" src="Imagens/skype.png" width="30" height="30"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.whatsapp.com">
    <div style=""><img class="logo" src="Imagens/whatsapp-messenger.png" width="30" height="30"></div>
  </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já pensou em usar o atributo "**margin**" ao invés de "**padding**".
Colocaria

`.logo {
   margin-top: 100px;
}`

por exemplo.

Outra coisa, poderia ver a opção de remover a tag "style" das suas *div*'s já que está usando o CSS, fica mais limpo o código.

Comment: Não, resultou :( parece k os icons estão colados ao vídeo.

Comment: Então o correto é você trabalhar com tags como header, footer, container, assim seu código fica mais organizado e assim você pode definir as positions das DIV's.
Da uma lida aqui nesse artigo da w3, mostra as possiveis positions https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp
Do jeito que você fez é como se todas as suas DIV's tivessem no mesmo lugar e por meio de gambiarras você está mudando as posições.